# Moving shortcode content into attribute using preg_replace()

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-replace

I'm using the following to replace the name of a shortcode:

```
$content = '[title type="1"]Test[/title]';
$pattern = '#\[title(.*)(.*?)\[/title\]#i';
$replace = '[new_title$1[/new_title]';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $content);
```

This works fine to change this:

```
[title type="1"]Test[/title]
```

To this:

```
[new_title type="1"]Test[/new_title]
```

But I'm trying to move the text between the tags into an attribute and make it self closing like so:

```
[new_title type="1" title="Test"]
```

Comment: Something like [`preg_replace('#\[title(.*?)](.*?)\[/title]#i', '[new_title$1 title="$2"]', $content)`](https://ideone.com/4t0M50)?

Comment: Try `#\[title([^]]*)]([^[]*)\[/title]#`and replace with `[newtitle$1 title="$2"]`. See live demo here https://regex101.com/r/wZFciO/1

Comment: Thank you, does exactly what I'm trying to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
$content = "[title type=\"1\"]Test[/title] [title]Test2[/title]\n [title type=\"6\"]Test With\nNewline 3[/title]";
$pattern = '#\[title(\s.*?)?](.*?)\[/title]#is';
$replace = '[new_title$1 title="$2"]';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $content);
```

See [this PHP demo](https://ideone.com/S5WnTh) and [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PpiNUZ/1). If you do not want to match titles with newlines in them, remove the `s` modifier that makes `.` match line break chars.

**Pattern details**

- `\[title` - a `[title` substring
- `(\s.*?)?` - an optional capturing group matching 1 or 0 occurrences of

  - `\s` - any whitespace
  - `.*?` - any 0+ chars, as few as possible
- `]` - a `]` char
- `(.*?)` - capturing group #2: any 0+ chars, as few as possible
- `\[/title]` - `[/title]` substring.

Answer (score 0):

Use `/\[(\w+)([^\]]+)](\w+).*/` as pattern in `preg_replace()`. In pattern `([^\]]+)` select every characters except `]`.

```
$newContent = preg_replace("/\[(\w+)([^\]]+)](\w+).*/", '[new_title$2 title="$3"]', $content)
```

Check result in [demo](https://3v4l.org/CQq4c)

Comment: *Use this regex* with making no words to explain it doesn't provide OP an answer to understand.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm trying to change this [title type="1"]Test[/title] to this, [new_title type="1" title="Test"], note that "title" changes to "new_title", Wiktor Stribiżew's  and revo's answers above are spot on

Comment: @TheBobster Fiexed

Comment: `.*` matches everything that comes after a closing tag i.e `[/title] [description]...`. You may want to replace that dot-star with an explicit closing tag to avoid this. And `\w+` matches much more than only `title` tags.

Comment: @revo In question, `[description]` doesn't exist and i try to provide simple pattern But your idea make pattern longer

Comment: In question `type="1"` exists as is. So does it mean `type` is always equal to `1`? Also OP is matching `title` specifically. Why do you want them to match all other tags too?